# jquery tools dateinput : addDay(amount)

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-tools

I am using [jquery tools date input](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/dateinput/index.html). In my application i have a feature that allows the user to check his personal data based on date range.

I have an input text field which loads the date Input functionality. When the user select a date it displays it in : **"dddd dd, mmmm yyyy"** format in the text field.
What i am trying to do is to add 7 days (ie a week) and display the new date in the upper range container, to explain more this is how it looks:

From: Friday 18, May 2012
To: //here is where i want it to be : Friday 25, May 2012

I am trying to use the built in api function :**addDay(amount)** but it seems not to work.
I have the following code:

```
var ret_date = $(this).data("dateinput").getValue('dddd dd, mmmm yyyy');
//I tried: $(this).data("dateinput").addDay(7).getValue('dddd dd, mmmm yyyy')
//but it kept the same currently selected date
$("#to_field").html(ret_date);
```

I searched online and SO but couldn't find a solution. I am not generally a front end developer so my knowledge with javascript/jquery is not advanced. 

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, this is what i ended up doing and it worked:

```
$("#DateField").change(function(event, date) {
        //I used format: yyyy-mm-dd
        var ret_date= $(this).data("dateinput").getValue('yyyy-mm-dd');   
        //Format the date using javascript
        //--> For that 2 javascript prototypes have been created(check at the end of the answer)          
        var myDate = new Date(ret_date);
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7);
        $("#FinalDateField").html(myDate.dateFormat("Y-m-d"));
});
```

The prototypes:

```
Date.prototype.dateFormat = function(format) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < format.length; ++i) {
    result += this.dateToString(format.charAt(i));
  }
  return result;
}

Date.prototype.dateToString = function(char) {
  switch (char) {
  case "Y":
    return this.getFullYear();
  case "m":
    return this.getMonth() + 1; //Since months are zero based, add 1
  case "d":
    return this.getDate();
  default:
    return char;
 }
}
```